# Angularjs form-validation

Tags: angularjs

i want that no body can save form without providing a name and here is my Html code ..what i am doing wrong i dont know ..i have checked many solutions please give me a reason...i want to know that how i will provide front-end validation

```
    <div class="vbox wrapper" ng-controller="CalendarAddController">
       <form id ="frmType" name="frmType" class="form-horizontal form-validation" novalidate method="get">
<div class="wrapper-v b-b col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
      <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right ">
        <a ui-sref="admin.calendar.entity" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        Cancel
        </a> 
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary " ng-click="frmType.$valid && save()">Save</a>    
    </div>  
    <div class="h4 text-black">Add Calendar</div>
</div>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<div class="wrapper-v col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
    </div>
    <h4 class="wrapper text-muted">Calendar</h4>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-md" style="clear:both;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="calendar.name" 
                placeholder="Enter calendar name" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="15" class="form-control"  ng-required="true" >
                <span class="error code">{{errMsg}}</span>
                <p class="help-block error-pattern">
                    Must start with a letter, may contain alphabets, digits and underscore.
                </p>
                <p class="error error-minlength">
                    Must be at least 1 character long.
                </p>
                <p class="error error-maxlength">
                    Length of "Name" field must not exceed 15 characters.
                </p>
               <span ng-show="frmType.name.$error.required && frmType.$submitted">Please provide role name</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8  col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter description" ng-maxlength="100" 
                ng-model="calendar.description" class="form-control" />
                <p class="error error-maxlength">
                    Must not exceed 100 characters.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Starting Day of Week</label>
                <div class="col-sm-1  col-lg-1 dd-width">
                 <select name="startingDay" class="form-control" ng-model="calendar.weekStartDay">
                       <option value="1">Sunday</option>
                       <option value="2">Monday</option>
                       <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
                       <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
                       <option value="5">Thursday</option>
                       <option value="6">Friday</option>
                       <option value="7">Saturday</option>
                 </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Working days & Timings</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                <h4 class="row text-bold">
                    <span class="col-md-12">
                        <span class="col-md-3">
                            Working Days
                        </span>
                        <span  class="col-md-6 ">
                            Timing
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </h4>
                <div class="row text-bold"  ng-repeat="calDay in calDays" >
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label class="i-checks i-checks-xs ">
                                    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="calendar.workingDays" ng-model="calDay.enabled"
                                        checklist-value="calDay.dayNum" ng-change="selectDay(calDay.dayNum)" ><i></i>{{calDay.dayName}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="col-md-6">
                            {{timingDay=corrTimingDay(calDay.dayNum);""}}
                            <div class="row" >
                                    <button class="btn btn-link" ng-disabled="!calDay.enabled" ng-click="open(timingDay)"
                                        style="margin-bottom:-12px;">Add time block</button>
                                    <span class="tooltipText"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timing-chips" ng-repeat="timingBlock  in timingDay.timingBlocks">
                                <span>{{intval(timingBlock.startTime/60)}}:{{makestr(timingBlock.startTime%60)}} 
                                {{ampm(timingBlock.startTime)}} &nbsp;   to &nbsp;
                                    {{intval(timingBlock.endTime/60)}}: 
                                    {{makestr(timingBlock.endTime%60)}} {{ampm(timingBlock.endTime)}}</span>&nbsp;
                                 <span class="hour">[{{totalTime(timingBlock.startTime,timingBlock.endTime)}} Hour]</span> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="remove fa fa-remove no-padder" ng-click="timingDay.timingBlocks
                                .splice(timingDay.timingBlocks.indexOf(timingBlock),1)">
                                </i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-md " style="clear:both;">
        <div class="wrapper-v col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <h4 class="wrapper text-muted cls-space ">Holidays
                <span class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary " ng-click="holidayOpen('lg')">Apply Holidays
                    </a> <input id="filter" type="text" ng-model="filterValue"
                       ng-change="filterTable()" placeholder="search"
                       class="form-control toolbar-item input-group w-xs  inline m-l-xs" />
               </span>
           </h4>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:5px;"> 
           <div class="wrapper-v-md" style="clear: both;">
               <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptionsHoliday" class="table table-striped clickable b-a table-condensed" >
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Name</th>
                           <th>Description</th>
                           <th>Date</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr ng-repeat="holiday in calendarHolidays">
                           <td>{{holiday.name}}</td>
                           <td>{{holiday.description}}</td>
                           <td>{{holiday.date}}</td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
       </div>
                <div class="wrapper-v  col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <h4 class="wrapper text-muted cls-space">Exceptions
                        <span class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary  " ng-click="exceptionOpen('lg')">Apply Exceptions
                            </a> <input id="filter" type="text" ng-model="filterValue"
                            ng-change="filterTable()" placeholder="search"
                            class="form-control toolbar-item input-group w-xs  inline m-l-xs" />
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9  col-sm-10 col-xs-12 " style="padding-bottom:5px;"> 
                    <div class="wrapper-v-md table-space" style="clear: both;">
                         <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptionsException" class="table table-striped clickable b-a table-condensed" >
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Name</th>
                           <th>Description</th>
                           <th>Date</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr ng-repeat="exception in calendarExceptions">
                           <td>{{exception.name}}</td>
                           <td>{{exception.description}}</td>
                           <td>{{exception.date}}</td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div></form>
    <!--  <pre>{{calendar |json}}</pre> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't dumb unnecessary code. Also please format the code you're posting. If you want to validate name just post the code for the form and name field and explain what you've tried. see [mcve]

Comment: @Chris Hermut reverted your edit because it removed the word "save". "saving form" and "form data" are different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `required` and see if it helps?

```
<input type="text" name="name" required>
```

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. It worked for me with your code so don't really know how else to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding onto @thepio's answer while you do that

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="calendar.name" 
                placeholder="Enter calendar name" required >
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="!frmType.$valid">
```

The last line will disable your submit button until user types something in it.

If you want to check for if all letters were words I suggest using ng-pattern.

An example of what I used in my code

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Executive Name</label>
    <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Executive Name" name="execName" ng-model="user.execName" ng-pattern="/^[A-z ]*$/" required />
    <span class="error" ng-show="createForm.execName.$error.required && createForm.execName.$touched">required</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="createForm.execName.$error.pattern && createForm.execName.$dirty">Must start with a letter, and contain letters only.</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i do not want to disable the button i want that when user submit the form without enter the name it will show the error that "please provide name"

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-message validation like:

```
 <form name="form" validate>
 <input id="name" name="name" md-maxlength="25"
                 ng-model="name" required autocomplete="false">

          <div ng-messages="form.name.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Name field can not empty</div>
          </div>
</form>
```

here if the full [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) about this.